# When using CSS display: table why does height 100% fail in IE10 and lower?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I've read a lot of articles that don't seem to explain or help solve this issue. So I'm hoping some CSS wiz can help out?

So I am using CSS table layout to achieve simple vertical alignment of styled divs. The outer div has a calculated size and the inner nested divs inherit size from their respective parents. All is good until you view in IE10 or below. Where both the row and cell decide their height is 0px. I believe this is due to no height being specified at row level so in IE the cell is unable to inherit the parent height. So if you add height 100% to the row it still works fine in all browsers other than IE 10 where the row decides its double height. The only thing I can think of is that IE is unhappy with, is I am placing a number of 100% divs in a container and letting them calculate their own equal sizes.

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  height: calc(100px + 10px);
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
}
.table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  display: table;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row;
  background-color: orange;
}
.block-1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
.tablecell {
  /* height: 100%; */
  display: table-cell;
}
.block-2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="tablecell">
        <div class="block-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="tablecell">
        <div class="block-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9ya5dvr/20/) notice if browsed in IE 10 or below both the red and blue dives cannot be seen as they now have zero height.

Comment: Your CSS = Your HTML?

Comment: Sorry cut/past fail :(

Comment: Have you tried simply setting `height:50%` for the `table-cell` elements? Makes it look in IE Edge, 10 and 9 as it does in Chrome, and doesn’t seem to change display in Chrome either.

Comment: The number of cells is dynamic at runtime, it could be one or many. So sadly fixed height is not an option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not using javascript (old webpages were heavy on javascript hacks to compensate the lack of css support in older browsers) this on is very small

```
adjustHeight();
window.addEventListener('resize', adjustHeight);

function adjustHeight(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    // or if you have jQuery it would be even more retro compatible without too much hassle
    // $('.container').css('height', window.innerHeight);
};
```

you can do vertical separation with javascript as well.

`$('container-half').css('height', window.innerHeight/2 );` is an example

** EDIT  **
now with your example

```js
adjustHeight();
window.addEventListener('resize', adjustHeight);

function adjustHeight(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
};
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  height: calc(100px + 10px);
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
}
.table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  display: table;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row;
  background-color: orange;
}
.block-1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
.tablecell {
  /* height: 100%; */
  display: table-cell;
}
.block-2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="tablecell">
        <div class="block-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="tablecell">
        <div class="block-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but what  I'm trying to do is understand what IE is doing so I can make the best judgement for a fix. While there are numerous ways to achieve the same result using different methods I am trying to find the least intrusive CSS change. if at all possible?

Comment: IE10 and lesser don't get 'computed' geometry from the window if it's not set in the CSS. you cannot really acheive this without javascript. What you can still do is work with absolute position (doesn't work in IE6 and lesser)  and setting bottom / top possition with a percentage

Comment: Hi, this still doesn't work in IE10 for me. The problem isn't the container height, (you can set that to a fixed height and it still fails) the problem seems to manifest when the blocks calculate their 100% height, in IE they are zero. I believe is due to no height specified in the parent (tablecell) if you un comment the height: 100% above then IE does calculate a height but unfortunately it sticks to 100% of the parent rather than sharing the height with siblings. So the result is the height gets doubled and the cells exceed the row height.